# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server'

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I'm editing a page on localhost, but suddenly it can no longer connect to the database. It times out after 60 seconds and gives the error given in the title of this post.

It is using the same connection as the live app (which is working). It has worked for years, and the code that sets up the database connection has ever been unchanged. Suddenly it decided to stop working.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Your MySQL server host name is really "server"?

Comment: <_< No, it is not.. I omitted the actual server name for this post.

Answer (score 0):

check your config.php especially this 2 credentials:
password && user

Becoz sometimes it (I don't know why????
) changes to "root", not "admin"...

Answer (score 0):

If you connected to database on external server ( == not locally installed), then,probably, server owner rebound mysqld to localhost for security reasons.
60 seconds is default socket timeout in PHP settings

Comment: How can I tell if it is being rebounded? All the other applications I work with are still connecting fine, just this one is failing to connect.

Comment: other applications uses same database server or not? If the same, another question: they uses same database? If answer is "yes", then recheck credentials in broken app.

Comment: Tests for "mysqld not binded to external interface":
if you have mysql commandline client, then run: `mysql -h server` (of course, replace _server_ with hostname or ip of your server). If not, then try to run in commandline: `telnet server 3306` . If you get `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`, then mysqld isn't accessible outside the server